# Can a For-loop be contained in a function?

Tags: procedural-programming

What I want to do here is evaluate

```
For[k = 1; t = Frr[1, 0, k], k < 1000, k++, 
  If[k >= 3, Break[], t = Flatten[t]*Frr[1, 0, k + 1]]];
t
```

in which `Frr[i, j, k]` is a function I need to evaluate many times in  this For-loop (three inputs: `i`, `j` and number to break — here it is 3.  How can I define a function that takes the three variables I need to control the loop.

Comment: What are you actually doing here with this loop? What is `Frr` supposed to do? It might be possible to solve your problem without loops if you could maybe talk about the *actual problem* you have.

Comment: I tried to put them on, but it's too long to put. since Frr related three other functions. Anyway Frr is a function with regard to three variables and comes out a list of values. Is this useful or not? otherwise I will give you all my code.

Comment: It would really help if you could write out what output you want to get. Leave it in terms of `Frr`, if you want. Or create a simpler, dummy function in it's place. You _might_ be looking for something like `Flatten[Frr[1, 0, #]] Frr[1, 0, # + 1] & /@ Range[1, 3]`, or maybe something involving [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) or [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html), but it's pretty hard to tell, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your particular example, you could just write

```
f0[i_, j_, kmax_] := Product[f[i, j, k], {k, kmax}]
```

then

```
f1[0, 1, 3]
```

> `f[0, 1, 1] f[0, 1, 2] f[0, 1, 3]`

However, it more likely that your example is just a toy problem standing in for a more complicated one. Assuming that and also that you are committed to using `For`, then you might write

```
f1[i_, j_, kmax_] :=
  Module[{t},
    For[k = 1; t = f[i, j, 1], k < 1000, k++,
      If[k >= kmax, Break[], t = t f[i, j, k + 1]]];
    t]

f1[0, 1, 3]
```

> `f[0, 1, 1] f[0, 1, 2] f[0, 1, 3]`

I really don't recommend the For-loop solution because it is very inefficient and verbose in Mathematica. Rather, I recommend using [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html).

```
f2[i_, j_, kmax_] := Module[{k = 1}, Nest[# f[i, j, k++] &, 1, kmax]]

f2[0, 1, 3]
```

> `f[0, 1, 1] f[0, 1, 2] f[0, 1, 3]`